# Email from a hacker with my password

Tags: passwords, email, scam

I have received an email from a hacker saying he got my email account password.
The password showed in the mail is not my account password but is a password I use sometimes.

I checked [haveibeenpwned](https://haveibeenpwned.com/) and the password don't report as leaked.

Considering :

- This is a scam to make me pay
- The password is a legit password I use
- The password is not used in sensitive services (banks, socials medias, anything with credit cards information)
- He claims to have installed a malware on my system.

What are the actions I can do? Besides changing this password on any website it is used and never use it again.